# How can i convert the code from VB to C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

For the practice mostly.
This is the code in VB :

```
Private Function ScrambleWord(ByVal word As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim builder As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    Dim random As Random = New Random()
    Dim index As Integer = 0

    Dim lower As Integer = 0
    Dim upper As Integer = 0

    Dim parts() As Char
    Dim part As Char

    If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(word)) Then
        If (word.Length > 3) Then
            parts = word.ToCharArray()
            builder.Append(word.Substring(0, 1))
            parts = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 2).ToCharArray()

            lower = LBound(parts) : upper = UBound(parts)
            For i = lower To upper
                index = random.Next(lower, upper)
                part = parts(index)
                parts(index) = parts(i)
                parts(i) = part
            Next
            builder.Append(parts)
            builder.Append(word.Substring(word.Length - 1, 1))
            Return builder.ToString()
        Else
            Return word
        End If
    Else
        Return String.Empty
    End If
End Function
```

I used an online translation site and ended with this:

```
private string ScrambleWord(string word)
{
    int i = 0;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    int index = 0;

    int lower = 0;
    int upper = 0;

    char[] parts = null;
    char part = '\0';

    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(word)))
    {
        if ((word.Length > 3))
        {
            parts = word.ToCharArray();
            builder.Append(word.Substring(0, 1));
            parts = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 2).ToCharArray();

            lower = Information.LBound(parts);
            upper = Information.UBound(parts);
            for (i = lower; i <= upper; i++)
            {
                index = random.Next(lower, upper);
                part = parts[index];
                parts[index] = parts[i];
                parts[i] = part;
            }
            builder.Append(parts);
            builder.Append(word.Substring(word.Length - 1, 1));
            return builder.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return word;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Im not sure if all the translation is good but now im getting two errors since Information not exist in c#

The errors are on the C# code on the lines:

```
lower = Information.LBound(parts);
upper = Information.UBound(parts);
```

Both errors are the same:

> The name 'Information' does not exist in the current context

I took the VB code from [this link](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/732026-vbnet-scrambling-text-between-the-first-and-last-letter/) and tried to convert it to c#

Comment: You're missing some details. What were the errors, and on which lines of code did you get them?

Comment: Try instead of lower = Information.LBound(parts); this lower = parts.GetLowerBound(0); and instead of upper = Information.UBound(parts); this upper = parts.GetUpperBound(0);

Comment: You can add a reference for Microsoft.VisualBasic and add `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;`

Comment: Are you practising converting VB.NET code to C#? The code as presented could do with a rewrite anyway.

Comment: `lower = LBound(parts) : upper = UBound(parts)` -> remove the **:** then run it through the code converter again.

Answer (score 3):

The [Information class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.information.aspx)
 comes from the [Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.aspx).

You can add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic and add `using Microsoft.VisualBasic` to the top of your file.

Answer (score 3):

You don't in fact have anything named `Information` in the current context. (There's nothing declared in the code you posted, either in VB or C#.)

You don't need it anyway. It's being used to access the bounds of the `parts` array, and you know them already. You used them to create the array in the first place. (And you don't need the `VisualBasic` namespace.)

```
parts = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 2).ToCharArray();
lower = 0;
upper = parts.Length;            // Note this is one higher than the last index,
                                 // because the first index is zero
for (i = lower; i < upper; i++)  // So use < rather than <= here
{
  // Other code here.
}
```

`LBounds` and `UBounds` were needed in VB because arrays didn't always have to start at a certain index, as [@competent_tech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383342/how-can-i-convert-the-code-from-vb-to-c/17384741?noredirect=1#comment25237641_17384741) mentions in the comments. It was possible to declare an array with different indexes, even negative ones (eg., `Dim parts(-3 To 3)`). Also, everything in VB was a variant, so an array could be any type or be multi-dimensional, and the compiler couldn't always tell them apart. (For instance, retrieving cells from Excel in a `Range` - the result can be one cell, an entire row, or a rectangular or square block of cells.) There's no need for them here, because you know `parts` is simply a one dimensional character array. Arrays in C# start at index zero, and there's a method to retrieve the length of the array. The last index into the array is one less than that length, as my code above indicates with comments.

Comment: +1 but you should mention that `UBound` returns `Length - 1`. So either use `upper = parts.Length - 1` or modify the for loop.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Noted. I'd automatically used `< upper` in my head instead of `<= upper`, but edited to include the sample loop in my answer. Thanks again for the catch. That's two I owe you. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: Just as an FYI, the description of why LBound, in particular, was necessary, is slightly off. In VB6, you could declare both the lower and upper bounds of an array so an array didn't always start at index 0 and in fact, it could even start at a negative number, i.e. Dim parts(-3 To 3). In fact, if memory serves, the default lower bound changed at some point in the VB lifecycle from 1 to 0 or vice versa. You are correct that multi-dimensional arrays were another reason for using L/UBound, since the second, optional param specified what dimension to get the bound for.

Comment: @competent_tech: Thanks for that info. I'm not all that familiar with VB6; I used it very briefly before I discovered Delphi, which was much better. :-) I'll edit to add the lower bounds explanation.

Comment: @KenWhite: No problem, I spent more time programming in VB (from 3.0 on) than I care to remember, so some of this is etched in my mind. For reference, here is the VB6 doc on LBound: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445057%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Change you code:

instead of

```
  lower = Information.LBound(parts);
  upper = Information.UBound(parts);
```

put

```
  lower = parts.GetLowerBound(0);
  upper = parts.GetUpperBound(0);
```

*Information* class is specific to VB; when writing C# code
you have to use an equivalent:

```
  Information.LBound(value) == value.GetLowerBound(0);
  Information.UBound(value) == value.GetUpperBound(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
private static string ScrambleWord(string word)
{
    // easy exits come first
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
        return String.Empty;

    if (word.Length <= 3)
        return word;

    // now do the work
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Random rand = new Random();

    builder.Append(word.Substring(0, 1));

    List<Char> parts = word.Substring(1).ToList();

    while (parts.Count() > 0)
    {
        int upper = parts.Count();
        int index = rand.Next(0, upper);
        builder.Append(parts[index]);
        parts.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Someone who is conversant in C# might point out mistakes.